# Are predefined variables in Gitlab CI/CD avaliable in .gitlab-ci.yml?

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I were trying to use CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA variable in config file (.gitlab-ci.yml), but it returned nothing.

I wanted to use CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA as part of directory name which were later pushed to the server by rsync. It should have returned short hash from current commit. Deployment passed successfully but the hash was empty.

```
deploy production:
    ...
    script:
        ...
        - VARIABLE_NAME=something_$CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA
        - echo $VARIABLE_NAME
```

Code above return just `something_` instead of e.g. `something_aef34a4x`

So can I use CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA or other predefined variables like this at all or what is the right way?

Comment: Try:  VARIABLE_NAME=something_${CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA}

Comment: @1615903 That is probably it. I thought that gitlab itself have always the last version mentioned in documentation but on [https://gitlab.com/help](https://gitlab.com/help) I have found that current version is 11.6.2-ee which is the reason why the variable was empty. Thank you for you help.

Comment: I added my comment as an answer so that you can mark it as accepted if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GIT_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA` was introduced in version 11.7: https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/variables/

As you have discovered, currently gitlab.com has version 11.6.2 installed, so the variable is not available (yet).